# How to update item by Composite Primary Key in Dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table called friends:

```
Friend 1 | Friend 2 | Status
```

Friend 1 is my HASH attribute and Friend 2 is my range attribute.

I would like to update an item's staus attribute where friend 1 = 'Bob' and friend 2 = 'Joe'. Reading through the documentation on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaDocumentAPICRUDExample.html I can only see how to update an item by 1 key, how do I include the other key?

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing example where you can make update of multiple item in single table. I have primary key as id and range key as Datetime. 
Actually there is no feature available in dynamodb so what i'm doing here is first query all the variable with hash key and range key of which i want to make update. Once all data are stored in List then loading data with it's hash key and rangekey and changing or updating field using set and save it.
Since I'm editing in hash key so, hash key original will be there we need to delete it. If you need to update in next attribute no need. I haven't added deleting code write yourself. You can query if you have confusion your entry with hash key will be still and new entry with new hash key will be added.
Code is below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
    DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);
    client.setEndpoint("http://localhost:8000/");
    String fromDate = "2016-01-13";
    String toDate = "2016-02-05";
    User user = new User();
    user.setId("YourHashKey");
    LocalDate frmdate = LocalDate.parse(fromDate, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
    LocalDate todate = LocalDate.parse(toDate, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
    LocalDateTime startfrm = frmdate.atStartOfDay();
    LocalDateTime endto = todate.atTime(23, 59, 59);
    Condition rangeCondition = new Condition().withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.BETWEEN.toString()).withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(startfrm.toString()), new AttributeValue().withS(endto.toString()));
    DynamoDBQueryExpression<User> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<User>().withHashKeyValues(user).withRangeKeyCondition("DATETIME", rangeCondition);
    List<User> latestReplies = mapper.query(User.class, queryExpression);
    for (User in : latestReplies) {
        System.out.println(" Hashid: " + in.getId() + " DateTime: " + in.getDATETIME() + "location:" + in.getLOCID());
        User ma = mapper.load(User.class, in.getId(), in.getDATETIME());
        ma.setLOCID("Ohelig");
        mapper.save(ma);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
DynamoDBQueryExpression<Reply> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<Reply>()
            .withKeyConditionExpression("Id = :val1 and ReplyDateTime > :val2")
            .withExpressionAttributeValues(
...
```

where Id is the Hash Key and ReplyDateTime is the Range Key.

Reference:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.QueryScanExample.html

Comment: The question was how to _update_ an item using a composite primary key, but this answer seems only to address _querying_ an item.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the question is using the AWS Java SDK 1.x. If you consider switching to the SDK 2.x, the DynamoDB documentation has an [example for updating an item](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.UpdateItem.html) which shows setting up a map with the key:

```java
HashMap<String,AttributeValue> itemKey = new HashMap<>();
itemKey.put(key, AttributeValue.builder()
    .s(keyVal)
    .build());
```

If you have a composite key, just add both key attributes to the map:

```java
HashMap<String,AttributeValue> itemKey = new HashMap<>();
itemKey.put(partitionKey, AttributeValue.builder()
    .s(partitionKeyVal)
    .build());
itemKey.put(sortKey, AttributeValue.builder()
    .s(sortKeyVal)
    .build());
```

This map is later passed to the update request exactly as is shown in the example on that page:

```java
UpdateItemRequest request = UpdateItemRequest.builder()
    .tableName(tableName)
    .key(itemKey)
    .attributeUpdates(updatedValues)
    .build();
```

As a side note, the online example currently uses:

```java
HashMap<String,AttributeValue> itemKey = new HashMap<>();
```

That is bad practice; you should program to interfaces. Thus the better code would be:

```java
Map<String,AttributeValue> itemKey = new HashMap<>();
```

If you're using Java 9+, you can use `Map.of(…)` to create the map in one statement rather than having separate `put(…)` commands. Whether you use `Map.of(…)` is a matter of preference.